# make average row with the same pattern

Tags: text-formatting

Hi there I have a huge table (10 column and 6000 row) and i have to make an average of all the row only if they have the same pattern in column 3 (ko).
My table contains numbers and string.

here an example

```
pvalue  padj    ko  pathway
17,14   0,01    ko00620 Pyruvatemetabolism
15,76   0,01    ko00620 Pyruvatemetabolism
13,22   0,00    ko00620 Pyruvatemetabolism
12,40   0,00    ko00051 Fructoseandmannosemetabolism
12,03   0,01    ko00051 Fructoseandmannosemetabolism
```

I would like to obtain something like this

```
pvalue  padj    ko  pathway
15,38   0,01    ko00620 Pyruvatemetabolism
12,22   0,00    ko00051 Fructoseandmannosemetabolism
```

Comment: What tools do you want to use to solve your problem? Windows/Unix? Excel/awk/R? You have to be more specific.

Comment: What code have you tried?